# is subcollection the best way to create a "friendlist" of players?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

im having a hard time with subcollections (this is my first flutter/firebase/nosql project)

I want to implement a "Friends List" inside the player collection, and i need a subcollection with the others players in the friendList, is this the best way to do it? if yes, how i add the subcollection into the document?

```
final CollectionReference playerCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('player');

Future updatePlayerData(
    String nickname,
    int gamesWon,
    int points,
  ) async {
    return await playerCollection.document(uid).setData({
      "nickname": nickname,
      "gamesWon": gamesWon,
      "points": points,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make **subCollection** inside **document** like this,

```
final CollectionReference playerCollection =
Firestore.instance.collection('player');

Future updatePlayerData(
    String nickname,
    int gamesWon,
    int points,
  ) async {
    return await playerCollection.document(uid).collection(frdUid).document(frdUid).setData({    
//frdUid is unique id
      "nickname": nickname,
      "gamesWon": gamesWon,
      "points": points,
    });
  }
```

Comment: The `.collection(frdUid)` is very unusual, and typically a bad idea. The reason for this is that you can't query collection names in the client-side SDKs, so you'll almost always use a hard-coded name for the collection. A more likely and idiomatic approach would be `.collection('friends').document(frdUid)...`

Comment: have you tried as you said in above comment? if yes then i'll update my answer